# Isolating and exporting specific sections of a shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, export, clip

If I have a shapefile layer in QGIS showing the spatial boundaries of subsections of a larger area (e.g. counties within a state, or countries within a continent), how would I selectively crop out one section of that shapefile and export it as its own shapefile (e.g. only Germany if I have all of Europe)? I don't want to crop by drawing a custom polygon around borders myself, as it needs to be exact for each subsection. Can this be done with attributes somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do a **query** (select by expression in the attribute table) and then save the elements selected by the query (query based on attributes) or make a **manual selection** in the map windows and save/export the layer using **selected features only** ...